# How to improve performance of Spring store procedure and property bean row mapper?

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures

I have extended `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure` to call oracle procedure, but I am facing serious performance issue. Please suggest best way to achieve good performance.

I think `BeanPropertyRowMapper` taking to much time to map cursor output to bean.
Total record return by procedure- 2469.
Execution time in sql developer - 1s
Execution time in java around 1.2 minutes.

```
public class TestingChart  extends StoredProcedure{

    public TestingChart(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, DbSubseaConstants.PKG_TEST_FATCHART_PRC);
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(DbSubseaConstants.MASTER_TEST_ID,OracleTypes.NUMBER));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(DbSubseaConstants.GET_REPORT_C2, OracleTypes.CURSOR,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<FATChart>(FATChart.class)));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(DbSubseaConstants.PO_ERROR_MESSAGE,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR));
        compile();
    }


    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> execute(Map<String, ?> inputs) {
        Map<String, Object> output = null;
        Map<String, Object> inputsParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Long masterTestId =  (Long) inputs.get(DbSubseaConstants.MASTER_TEST_ID);
        inputsParams.put(DbSubseaConstants.MASTER_TEST_ID, masterTestId);
        output = super.execute(inputsParams);
        return output;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. The execution time in sql developer is only the sql and displaying  result. It doesn't involve managed database resources, iterating over the results and creating java objects. Depending on the number of columns, 1.2 minutes can be fast or slow. Fact is that a custom `RowMapper` will probably be faster then the reflective `BeanPropertyRowMapper` (although in newer spring versions a lot of performance fixes have been done).